# How to log out of a specific account in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, imap

I have multiple IMAP accounts set up in my Thunderbird.  I mainly use one, but occasionally need to check another one.  When I'm done using the occasional one, I would like to log out of it.  Currently the only way I know to do this is close Thunderbird completely, get back in, and then only log into the main one again.

BTW, I'm running Thunderbird 2.0.0.23 on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Tools > Account Settings > Server Settings (of the account in question) > Advanced

clear the box **Include this server when getting new mail**

in order to receive mails for this account, click the arrow right to **Get Mail** and from the drop down menu select the account you just have exluded from receiving mails automatically.

HTH

Comment: Hmm not seeing that checkbox, the advanced dialog just has a bunch of IMAP settings, nothing about getting new mail.  Also, I don't want it to just not get new mail, I don't want the IMAP folders readable without logging in again.

Comment: IMAP is adifferent story altogether, you should have clarified this in your OP. the settings above refer to POP3 accounts. sorry.

Comment: You mean like the first sentence where he says "I have multiple IMAP accounts set up in my Thunderbird."? And the posting tags "thunderbird" and "imap"?

Comment: @user159796 - OP (Ryan McKay) edited the question to include **`IMAP`** in the question (and Dennis Williamson added IMAP tag) after Molly7244's answer and comment. Check revisions of question to see edits at Aug 27 '09 at 16:10 and Aug 27 '09 at 16:14.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on your account on the left panel -> Settings -> expand "Account Actions" -> Remove Account

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try removing saved login**

Maybe you checked the remember password box one time when logged in.

1. Click Edit on tool bar
2. Click Preferences on the menu
3. Choose Security on the left
4. Pick Passwords page
5. Click Saved Passwords button
6. Select the account
7. Click Remove

**Try the logout extension**

1. Follow [this link to the download](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/logout/) or google it.
2. Save the file
3. Open Thunderbird
4. Click Tools
5. Choose Add ons
6. Click Extensions on the left
7. Click the gear / down arrow button
8. Choose Install Add-on from file
9. Select the file and load
10. Restart Thunderbird
11. Right click the account on the left
12. Choose Logout